# Discord.py on_member_join event

Tags: python, discord.py

I need help with my code, i wanted to make my bot sends a message on the first channel from the top when a particular member joins, but i got error with `if member.id == *id*`

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    if member.id == *my id here, i just dont want to show it*
        await message.channel.send('Nice guy joined the server!')
```

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    if member.id == 660959014691143691:
        await member.guild.text_channels[0].send('Nice guy joined the server!')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't defined the `message` so you can't use `message.channel.send`. If you just want to send the first channel of the guild, that's simple to do with `guild.text_channels`.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    if member.id == *my id here, i just dont want to show it*
        await member.guild.text_channels[0].send('Nice guy joined the server!')
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still shows an error `Traceback (most recent call last):` and it shows it's around the ID: `if member.id == 660959014691143691`, but ID is correct.

Comment: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/660959471346122780/776869706023043082/unknown.png screenshot

Comment: When you're using a if statement, you have to add `:` at the end of the statement. I guess you forgot it.

Comment: Ok, thanks, i forgot. Now script works, but bot doesn't send any message, yes, it got permissions.

Comment: Can you add your newest code to your post and did you define the intents?

Comment: Ok, second one is the newest

Comment: I don't see any reason for this code not to work. Can you check if `on_member_join` event works by adding `print(member)` in the first line of the event function and did you define the intents?